# Getting assettype and assetgroup field values from feature class with domain using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, cursor, domains

I am trying to get the field values of assettype and assetgroup  from a feature class but I am not able to get the values there are subtypes assigned to those fields and also values are domain coded values in those fields.

```
fcs = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(target_fc)]
for fild in ['ASSETGROUP', 'ASSETTYPE']:
    if fild in fcs:
       searchfield = True
    if searchfield == True:
       with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(target_fc, ['ASSETGROUP', 'ASSETTYPE']) as cursor:
         for row in cursor:
            print(row)
```

Comment: What is the problem, do you get any error messages?

Comment: I'm not getting error but the problem is i need the domain coded values and i get only the code not the values.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.